# can i make php with laragon? and how to run a php script on bowser using laragon?

Tags: php, matrix, laragon

this is source code in file php

> how to run a php script on bowser using laragon?

```
<?php
$batas = 5;
echo '<table>';
for ($i=1;$i<=$batas;$i++){
    echo '<tr>';
    for ($j=1;$j<=$batas;$j++){
        echo '<td>';
        echo $i.$j;
        echo '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Set your document root in settings (i like to use *C:\workspace*)
This is the place that your projects will be loaded from.

2) Run your script in your browser like:

```
localhost/matrix.php
```

If your script is inside your root folder it should work fine.

If you have nested folders then you must give the path in your URL.

For example if your php script is inside a folder named **matrix**

Then your url should be : `localhost/matrix/matrix.php`

Comment: Page not found, why?

Comment: What is your file structure? How did you set your root path in the settings?

Comment: well, I have found the problem, so the file should be placed on localhost C: \ laragon \ www \ matrix, it can only be run in the browser, ok thank you :)

Comment: If this is your root then yes. I create my own root folder outside of the laragon file and just point it to get my localhost from there.